# Replace Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Hi I have an Ajax Action Link that works perfectly and it shows some text from a partial view once I click on the link, the thing is I want these texts to be shown once the page loads without clicking the action link. I'm new to this and I've already searched on google but nothing helps.

Here's the code

View.cshtml

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show my Text", "_Text",
new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET", 
                    UpdateTargetId = "ajaxdiv",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
                })

 <div id="ajaxdiv"></div>
```

Partial View:  _Text.cshtml

```
@model Website.MyViewModel

@foreach (TextTable item in Model.TextList)
{
    <h5> @item.UserText </h5>  
}
```

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult  _Text()
    {

        DBEntities DB = new DBEntities();
        var sessionID = Session["id"];
        int SessionID = Convert.ToInt32(sessionID);
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel
        {

            TextList= DB.TextTable.ToList()
        };

        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add OnSuccess in your ajax options and make jquery function that will hide it.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show my Text", "_Text",
new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET", 
                    UpdateTargetId = "ajaxdiv",
                    OnSuccess = "hideFunction",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
                })
```

In your js make a function like.

```
function hideFunction() {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: might be possible you are not implementing in the right way. otherwise it should work

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in explaining, I added your code to my project now the button is hidden after i click on it, i want the ajax function to be loaded without clicking on it